# Is Salafi a school of thought?

Tags: salafi

Is Salafi a school of thought like the maliki, shafi'i, hanbali and hanafi fiqhs?
 Or is Salafi a movement?
 Can one be a shafi'i and be a salafi?
 Please provide proof with your answer.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please take your time to learn more about our site and the stack exchange model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help].

Comment: You ask for proofs: What kind of proofs do you like to have? For this we must assume that salafi's themselves are in consensus of the meaning of the term we maybe than could give a proof ... most salafi's are more or less following the hanbali school of fiqh, but the major difference between them and the other four schools is not a fiqh (jursiprudence) rather than a 'aqidah (interpretation of the belief) matter.